# mount cifs via proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, mount

I am trying to mount a windows shared folder via a proxy as the machine in question is behind a firewall. I can mount the resource just fine from within the network using

```
sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER.DOMA.IN/folder/ /folder -o username=user,domain=DOMA.IN
```

I did not find any questions that mention mounting via proxy, there is [this post in ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081748) which asks more or less the same question but has no real answer.

I tried to adapt what is used in that question and tried to open a tunnel

```
ssh -l user -C -L 1139:SERVER.DOMA.IN:139 PROXY.DOMA.IN
```

and then point mount to localhost 1139

```
sudo mount -t cifs //localhost/folder/ /folder --verbose -p 1139 -o username=user,domain=DOMA.IN
```

but this simply fails with a

> mount error(6): No such device or address

Is this type of operation possible in principle and I am just doing something wrong, or is there an intrinsic limitation that makes this impossible?

Comment: If this is possible (and ive not tried it, and would have thoiught you  need more then just port 139 - but the linked answer seems to play otherwise), I wonder if your issue might be that SAMBA is not answering on localhost?   Why not try using sshfs  to mount the remote filesystem rather them cifs?